# How to remove selection from radio button?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to remove selection from radio checkbox using JQuery.

Here is HTML and radio buttons:

```
 <div data-role="popup" id="popupShapes" data-theme="none" style="z-index:999" data-dismissible="true" data-close-btn="right">
        <a href="#" data-rel="back" data-role="button" data-theme="b" data-icon="delete" data-iconpos="notext" class="ui-btn-right">Close</a>
        <div data-role="collapsibleset" data-theme="b" data-content-theme="a" style="margin:0; width:250px;">
            <div data-role="listview" data-inset="false">
                <ul data-role="listview">
                    <li>
                        <input type="radio" name="type" value="point" id="pointToggle" />
                        <label for="pointToggle">Point</label>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <input type="radio" name="type" value="line" id="lineToggle" />
                        <label for="lineToggle">Line</label>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <input type="radio" name="type" value="polygon" id="polygonToggle" />
                        <label for="polygonToggle">Polygon</label>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div><!-- /collapsible -->
        </div><!-- /collapsible set -->
    </div><!-- /popup -->
```

At some point I need to remove selected input radio button.

Here how I do it:

```
  $('#popupShapes ul input').prop('checked', false);
```

But the row above doesn't work.  The radio button stay selected.

How to remove selection from radio button?

Comment: Just add a `<input> None` and select that :)

Comment: when you're unselecting those inputs ? on load or on a button click , or .. !

Comment: radiobuttons by design are "required", so you shouldn't really offer your user an option of not selecting any of the options. if you insist on having it, add another option, as suggested above

Comment: @bRIMOs when some event is fired

Comment: @Michael that's weird  it should remove selection , unless there is an error in console before reaching this instr ..

Comment: The example above appears to work https://jsfiddle.net/4w7kd13d/
As others have asked when, or from where are you calling it?

Answer (score 2):

This simple script allows you to uncheck an already checked radio button. Works on all javascript enabled browsers.

```
<html>
    <!-- html from your link: [http://jsfiddle.net/wuAWn/][1]  -->
    <body>
        <input type='radio' class='radio-button' name='re'>
        <input type='radio' class='radio-button' name='re'>
        <input type='radio' class='radio-button' name='re'>
    </body>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var allRadios = document.getElementsByName('re');
        var booRadio;
        var x = 0;
        for(x = 0; x < allRadios.length; x++){

            allRadios[x].onclick = function() {
                if(booRadio == this){
                    this.checked = false;
                    booRadio = null;
                }else{
                    booRadio = this;
                }
            };
        }
    </script>
</html>
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/5xmgm600/)